# Regex, Php And Referrer?

Tags: php, regex, refer

I am trying to code a script, to redirect user when he comes from site like

```
http://www.something.com/url?sa=xxx



**http://www.something.com/url?sa=**t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblackorwhiteipad.blogspot.com%2F2012%2F03%2Fblack-or-white-ipad.html&ei=etyET5LlFoyk8QTZ0cXMCA&usg=AFQjCNEXBM1y-KlBQOORpuxqLAzVqzlGTQ&sig2=JIweuoccpZFkNKj_Xy04JA
```

but if user comes from this

```
http://www.something.com/url?**ga**=aldslakslaskl
```

He should not be redirected.

xxx = more strings after it. (unknown)

But script should not do anything if user comes from other Referrer

Here is my php code, but its not working.IDK why?

```
<?php

  session_start();

 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']=="http://www.something.com/url?**sa**=aldslakslaskl*string*") { 
redirect();
}
else
{donothing();
}
?>
```

Why this script is not working, what modification does this script need?

Also, i need to Call this Function "Onclick" Button.
But if button is click, refer of the parent page will be changed to parent page itself.
So how can i call this function onclick for a button, that's on page?
Regards

Comment: You are not using regex. You are comparing a string to the `HTTP_REFERER` as it is. Do you want to not redirect users coming from urls with a `ga` query param?

Comment: Yeah, i want user to be redirected only when he comes from http://www.something.com/url?sa=xxx   ,xxx- anything after that

Comment: But it want to use regex, can you show me a way how can i implement regex for this?

Comment: Just posted an answer. Give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(preg_match("/google\.com(.+?)sa=(.+?)/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        redirect();
    }
?>
```

Comment: but if user comes from another.com/url?sa=xxx

Comment: You mean you want it to be domain specific, for example, only from google.com?

Comment: do u want all users other than google referred to be redirected to the same address?

Comment: @ValNolav Check my question, i edited it t avoid any confusion.

Comment: Perfect, as soon as implement it on a Button on "My page"

Comment: It gave another problem, as if the button is click " it will initiate " , preg.php and the refer of this "preg.php will be changed to //www.something.com/url?sa=xxx

Comment: `onclick()` is Javascript, and it doesn't make any sense in the context of your question which is PHP. Please explain better with example code in your question.